# What is the time complexity of sorting datatype vector< pair<int, vector<int> > > ? ( As the swap needs to swap vectors ))

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, swap, std-pair

My datatype and sort function look like below:

```
vector< pair< int, vector<int> > > data;

sort(data.begin(),data.end(),[]( auto a,auto b )
{
    return a.first<b.first;
});
```

It will need to swap vectors too. Does the swap operation need to copy and paste all the elements of the vectors making the complexity of swap linear to the length of the two vectors to be swapped? Or will it do some trick (ex: pointer operation) to make it a constant time operation?

Comment: `vector` swap is cheap. It just moves a few pointers around. Ought to be constant.

Comment: [cppreference says constant.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap).

Comment: Assuming that `std::sort` uses `std::swap` (very likely), then there's a `std::vector` [specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap2) which invokes [`std::vector<T>::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) which doesn't do any per-element copying or moving. In short it already does "pointer operation" to optimize the swapping.

Comment: Even if swapping vectors was expensive, it wouldn't affect complexity of the sorting algorithm (which for `std::sort()` is O(n log(n)) where `n` is the number - in this case - of pairs to be sorted).   The cost of swapping vectors is constant, which may change execution time but doesn't affect complexity.

Comment: @Peter: It (would) depends of parameter we take into account. Complexity is actually `O(swap_complexity(m) * n log n)`. if `swap_complexity` was not constant, we would have 2 parameters to take into accounts.

Comment: Is it the case to almost all the programming languages ? or the swap is a constant operation in only the languages that allows pointer operations. what about python or java ?